# Grails functional test Geb page object module not working No signature of method

Tags: grails, groovy, spock, functional-testing, geb

This is the page object.

```
package myapp.pages
import geb.Page

class LoginPage extends Page {
    static url = "http://localhost:8080/login/auth"
    //static at = {title.contains("Login")}
    static at = {
        waitFor {title.contains("Login")} // Add waitFor here to verify on page
    }
    static content = {
        loginForm { $( 'form') }
        usernameField { $('form').userName }
        passwordField { $('form').password }
        submitButton { $('input#submit' )}
    }

    void  loginSubmit(String email, String password) {
        usernameField = "email@something.com"
        assert $('form').username == "email@something.com"
        passwordField = "secret"
        assert $('form').password == "secret"
        submitButton.click()
    }
}
```

And this is the LoginSpec test file

```
package myapp.login

import geb.spock.GebSpec
import grails.testing.mixin.integration.Integration
import grails.transaction.*
import myapp.pages.LoginPage

@Integration
@Rollback
class LoginSpec extends GebSpec {

    def setup() {
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }

    void "user successfully logs in, is redirected to homepage"() {
        given:
        to LoginPage

        when:
        LoginPage.loginSubmit("email@something.com", "secret")

        then:
        title.contains("Dashboard")
    }
}
```

When i run this test, I get the following error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static myapp.pages.LoginPage.loginSubmit() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [email@something.com.com, secret]
```

I basically get the same error when I hardcode the username and password into the login page loginsubmit function. The selectors are fine, when I use the same selectors directly in the LoginSpec test to set the username and password, the test passes. The issue only occurs when I try to use the page object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
    when:
    LoginPage.loginSubmit("email@something.com", "secret")
```

Use this:

```
    when:
    loginSubmit("email@something.com", "secret")
```

The issue isn't really a Geb one.  The JVM doesn't allow you to invoke an instance method on a class reference as the context necessary to carry out that invocation wouldn't exist.  `loginSubmit` is an instance method, not a static method.

I hope that helps.

Comment: This solved the problem, thanks, and for the additional context!

Comment: If you want to keep IDE autocomplete support I'd suggest to use `LoginPage loginPage = to LoginPage` in the given-block and then in the when-block `loginPage.loginSubmit("email@something.com", "secret")`.  Like kriegaex suggested in the other answer.

Comment: @LeonardBrünings one problem with that is that a `to` in a `when:` block is often followed by a `at` in a `then:` block.  Assigning the`to` return value to a statically typed reference will be a problem with the `to` results in a redirect.

Comment: You can assign the results of `at` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Geb remembers the current page and automatically dispatches method calls to the page, so you do not need to include the page class name: `loginSubmit("email@something.com", "secret")` in the test will call the method on the page.

Comment: But that does not explain the mistake the OP made and the corresponding error message. The real problem is calling instance method `loginSubmit` as if it was static via `LoginPage.loginSubmit(..)`. Instead he should call it like you with the page being set implicitly in the specification or explicitly via `def loginPage = to LoginPage; loginPage.loginSubmit(..)`. A good answer should explain the root cause of the problem, not just provide a solution without explanation.

Comment: This also solved the problem, and it's useful to know that Geb remembers the current page, thank!